# Proj of the direct sum of two graded rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, projective-schemes

Let us fix the notation. Let $V$ be a 4-dimensional complex vector space and let $$\mathbb P(V)=\operatorname{Proj}(\operatorname{Sym}V)=\operatorname{Proj}(\mathbb C[x,y,z,w]).$$
Consider the $\mathbb C^*$-action on $\mathbb P(V)$ given by
$$t \cdot [x:y:z:w]=[t^{-1}x:t^{-1}y:tz:tw].$$
Since $\mathbb C^*$ is a reductive algebraic group, the ring of invariant polynomials on $V$ is finitely generated and it holds
$$\mathbb C[V]^{\mathbb C^*}=(xz,xw,yz,yw) \subset \mathbb C[V]=\mathbb C[x,y,z,w].$$
Let us consider the quotient $\mathbb C[V]/(xz,xw,yz,yw)$: there is a surjective map $\mathbb C[V] \to \mathbb C[V]/(xz,xw,yz,yw)$, hence there is an inclusion
$$A:=\operatorname{Proj}\left(\frac{\mathbb C[V]}{(xz,xw,yz,yw)}\right) \subset \mathbb P(V).$$
Let us define $V_- \subset V$ and $V_+ \subset V$ to be the invariant subspaces of $V$, that is such that
$$\mathbb P(V_-)=\operatorname{Proj}(\mathbb C[x,y]), \qquad \mathbb P(V_+)=\operatorname{Proj}(\mathbb C[z,w]).$$

**Question:**
Does it hold that $A=\mathbb P(V_-) \sqcup \mathbb P(V_+)$?

Comment: You say ‘ring’ of invariant functions but seem to write it down as an ideal?